# How to download multiple images through the link?

Tags: image

I have the links of the image, I need to download all (about 3 thousand), is there a way to download these images directly through the link?

Comment: yes, it is. With that description of your problem i guess you don't need anything else; nah, have a look on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551419/download-list-of-images-from-urls

Comment: Thanks @TiGreX ;)