# Renaming list of Google Image URLs and saving in new folder

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, woocommerce, google-sheets, renaming

I know what I want to do but I can't figure out where to start I'm afraid.

- do I need python?
- or can Excel or Google Sheets do this with a script?

---

1. In a Google sheet which stores data on 100 products in our forthcoming e-commerce store, I have 100 images, each with a unique URL in Col A.

   Each product has an image pointing to our Google docs, eg `<a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXX`>...`
2. I want to rename those images with the product code of each image, in Col B, for example, VFBARCL-70.jpg, and save in a new folder in Google docs,  so we can upload the images via our CSV file to the WooCommerce store.
3. As a separate question, how can Excel open an image in Excel, from its URL?

Please, can someone help?

I've looked at [download list of images from urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551419/download-list-of-images-from-urls) but this doesn't help, and I found this code:

```
function convertToImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var colnum = 3;             // assuming column C; change to another column number
  var cell;
  var values = range.getValues(); 
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][colnum-1]) {
      cell = range.getCell(i+1, colnum);
      cell.setFormula('=image("'+values[i][colnum-1]+'")')
    }
  } 
}
```

Which at least opens the URLs as images in Google, but I don't know how to (i) run the script, and (ii) modify it to rename and resave the images into a different folder.

Comment: @player0, thanks for editing, I'll know for next time

Answer (score 0):

## Copy, Move and Rename Images based on values in a Spreadsheet

This is very similar to what you want to do:

```
function copyMoveAndRenameImages() {
  var srcfldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('source folder id');//source folder
  var desfldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('destination folder Id');//destination folder
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet94');//put your sheetname here
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);//getting data in columns 1 and 2
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var files=srcfldr.getFiles();//getting files in sources folder
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    if(file.getName().slice(0,3)=='die') {//I am picking files with a certain name
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
        if(vA[i][0]==file.getName().slice(0,4)) {//if filename = value in column 1
        //In your case you will compare image url to url in column1 I think
          file.makeCopy(Utilities.formatString('%s.jpg', vA[i][1]),desfldr);
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I think this is close to what you want but I will require more information about the urls and how to correlate the image names to the desired new image names.